# Get oracle date

Tags: oracle, datetime, oracle11g

I need to find out closest 7AM date. It can be today (if is 00-07AM) or tomorow (if is 07AM-12PM).
Is there something that can do this "inline" not with `if` statement?

Comment: You can use a case statement for this no?

Comment: i was thinking about something (i will it use in api calling)   schema.api_func.func(param1, param2, param3, {trunc(sysdate)+7/24})                               in {} i want to use as simplest sentence as is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adjust the date before truncating it; with some fake `sdate` values in place of the real `sysdate`:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

with t as (
    select to_date('01/02/2013 00:00:00') as sdate from dual
    union all select to_date('01/02/2013 06:59:59') from dual
    union all select to_date('01/02/2013 07:00:00') from dual
    union all select to_date('01/02/2013 07:00:01') from dual
    union all select to_date('01/02/2013 23:59:59') from dual
    union all select to_date('02/02/2013 00:00:00') from dual
)
select sdate,
    trunc(sdate + interval '17' hour) + interval '7' hour
from t
order by sdate;

SDATE               TRUNC(SDATE+INTERVA
------------------- -------------------
01/02/2013 00:00:00 01/02/2013 07:00:00
01/02/2013 06:59:59 01/02/2013 07:00:00
01/02/2013 07:00:00 02/02/2013 07:00:00
01/02/2013 07:00:01 02/02/2013 07:00:00
01/02/2013 23:59:59 02/02/2013 07:00:00
02/02/2013 00:00:00 02/02/2013 07:00:00
```

So `trunc(sysdate + interval '17' hour)` would give you midnight today if it's before 07:00:00, and midnight tomorrow if it's 07:00:00 or later; then `+ interval '7' hour` makes it 07:00:00 on whichever day the first resolved to.

You could use `+ 17/24` and `+ 7/24` instead of the intervals, but I think the intervals are easier for someone to understand later.

This assumes that if you run it exactly 07:00:00, that counts as tomorrow; if that's wrong then you can adjust by a second:

```
with t as (
    select to_date('01/02/2013 00:00:00') as sdate from dual
    union all select to_date('01/02/2013 06:59:59') from dual
    union all select to_date('01/02/2013 07:00:00') from dual
    union all select to_date('01/02/2013 07:00:01') from dual
    union all select to_date('01/02/2013 23:59:59') from dual
    union all select to_date('02/02/2013 00:00:00') from dual
)
select sdate,
    trunc(sdate + interval '16:59:59' hour to second) + interval '7' hour
from t
order by sdate;

SDATE               TRUNC(SDATE+INTERVA
------------------- -------------------
01/02/2013 00:00:00 01/02/2013 07:00:00
01/02/2013 06:59:59 01/02/2013 07:00:00
01/02/2013 07:00:00 01/02/2013 07:00:00
01/02/2013 07:00:01 02/02/2013 07:00:00
01/02/2013 23:59:59 02/02/2013 07:00:00
02/02/2013 00:00:00 02/02/2013 07:00:00
```

Comment: trunc(sdate + interval '17' hour) + interval '7' hour
this was i looking for, thanks

Comment: from what oracle version is this code compatible? (=will it run on 10g?)

Comment: @ondrotadanai - it works back to at least 9i; not sure when intervals were added.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you today if time < 07:00 or tomorrow otherwise.

```
trunc(sysdate+17/24)
```

trunc removes the time part of a date. 
17/24 adds 17 hours to the current time.

Comment: O, just see that you already know this. So now I am confused about what it is you are actually asking.

Comment: thanks for answer
so if i want know also a time it should be:
trunc(sysdate+17/24)+7/24
true? thanks at all